# Getting posts from both tables?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have 3 tables. User, Post, and Share. Post is a table that contains all posts. Post has a one to many relationship with Share. That being said, the Share table is a table where it indicates which posts a user has shared. Here's the structure of the tables:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status      = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    share_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    created_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    url         = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Share(models.Model):
    post        = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shared_at   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

What I want specifically is a query that gets what posts the user has shared and the posts the user has created. For example, let's say we have the same data:

**Post table**

```
id    user    status    share_count    created_at    url
1      1       hello         32         2017-06-01   hello
2      2       What's up     22         2017-07-01   whats-up
```

**Share table**

```
post    user   shared_at
2       2      2017-07-02
```

I want a query that will get a user's shared posts + their posts. So let's say I want to do that for user 1. The result should be post 1 and post 2 since the user posted post 1 and also shared post 2 from user 2. I have made this query, but for some reason only the shared posts are shown and not the user's posts as well. How do I make it so that the user's posts are shown with their shared posts? Is it possible to do it in one query?

```
Share.objects.all().select_related('post').filter(user=1)
```

Comment: i think not possible

Comment: Post.objects.all().select_related('user').filter(user=1) can you try this???

Comment: @HemanthSP Hmm, should it be `select_related('share').filter(user=1)`? Neither works, if I do `select_related('user')` then it only shows the user's posts. If I do `select_related('share')` it says share is not valid input for `select_related` Is there any way to get both user's shares and their posts?

Comment: Post.objects.all().select_related('user').filter(user=1) from this you will get user created post and shared post also. if you want to differneciate like post and share  write your own simple django query

Comment: @HemanthSP How do I retrieve the shared posts?

Comment: check Burhan Khalid answer

Answer (score 2):

You can query from the `User` model, since its common to both.

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=1) # pick a user

own_posts = user.post_set.all()
shared_posts = user.share_set.all()
```

To sort these so that you have a combined list of 5 recent posts, you have to order the posts by their timestamp, and then filter them:

```
from itertools import chain

user = User.objects.get(pk=1) # pick a user

own_posts = user.post_set.order_by('-created_at')
shared_posts = user.share_set.order_by('-shared_at')

combined = itertools.chain(own_posts, shared_posts)

def get_ts(obj):
   try:
     return obj.created_at
   except AttributeError:
     return obj.shared_at

last_5 = sorted(combined, key=get_ts, reverse=True)[:5]
```

Comment: Hmm, is it possible to write a query that gets 5 of the most recent posts from both posts and shares? Like for example, let's say the user has shared 10 and has 5 posts. We get the posts from both tables that are most recent for that user?

Comment: You mean combined you want 5 posts, or you want 5 posts, and 5 shares, so 10?

Comment: Combined 5 posts. So the most recent 5 shares and posts from that user in descending order

Comment: hmm, your solution almost worked, but the table `Share` doesn't have a field named `created_at`, it has a field named `shared_at` so the last line doesn't work and gives an error. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: When I do this: `last_5 = sorted(combined, key=operator.attrgetter('shared_at'), reverse=True)[:5]` it gives a blank array

Comment: Hmm, the updated solution still returns a blank array for some reason

Comment: I am getting this error after I do the last line: `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'`